# OpenCV HoughLines Produces Too Many Lines Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I have been working on using python and computer vision to detect the board state of a gameboard in a game called [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)). Based on the data collected [here](https://www.kaggle.com/davids1992/initial-data-analysis-go-board-recognition/data), I planned to base my implementation off of [this paper](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/thirsima/gocam/gocam.pdf)'s algorithm(s). However, I ran into trouble when I got to section **3.1.2** in the paper and had to compute a Hough Transform on my image. I tried using [OpenCV's Hough Line function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html), but got an image so full of lines I couldn't see the original image.

I tried various line thicknesses, and different thresholds values for previous functions but I always seemed to end up with either way too many lines or practically no lines at all. For example, when using the top image, I got the image below it with the code I pasted at the very bottom [image]

[image: Hough Image]

I assume that the though HoughLines function just produces so many lines that it covers the screen, but I can't seem to get a normal amount of lines. I'm not sure if this bit will be useful but I have to go to extremely high values of threshold compared to any tutorial or example I can find online to avoid an almost completely red screen, but even then only like 5 lines show up. I could just not use the HoughLines function but the next step of the paper depends on this result and so I either have to solve this or find a completely different implementation of this. Any help is appreciated on this. Thanks!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(pathreal, 1)
middlex = img.shape[1]/2
middley = img.shape[0]/2

def gaussianweights(image):
   newarr = [[0 for i in range(image.shape[1])] for j in range(image.shape[0])]
   for i in range(image.shape[1]):
      for j in range(image.shape[0]):
         x,y = i,j
         filtered = np.exp(((x-middlex)**2)/((middlex**2)/2)+((y-middley)**2)/((middley**2)/2))
         newarr[j][i] = image[j][i]*filtered
   return newarr

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

weighted_img = gaussianweights(img_gray)
filtered_img = cv2.filter2D(img_gray,-1, np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,-24,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]))
            
dst = cv2.Canny(filtered_img, 600, 800, None, 3)


lines = cv2.HoughLines(dst,1,np.pi/180,100)
for line in lines:
   for rho,theta in line:
      a = np.cos(theta)
      b = np.sin(theta)
      x0 = a*rho
      y0 = b*rho
      x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
      y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
      x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
      y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

      cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

 cv2.imshow("Hough Image",img)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**EDIT:**

Here's dst since some people asked

[image: dst]

Comment: `weighted_img` and `filtered_img` are not used and `new_img` is not defined. Please give use a reproducible/working example.

Comment: Did you have a look at how dst = cv2.Canny looks like? You could try lineSegmentDetector instead of canny

Comment: @JérômeRichard It should be updated, just a typo since I tried to make the code more readable

Comment: @Micka Updated with the image, I'll try lineSegmentDetector when I get a minute

Comment: You could try to increase the accumulator threshold value (the 100 in your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code on [OpenCV's Hough Line function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) I acheive this :[image]

Maybe you can start from that code...

Comment: Hm, so somewhere in my process, image got warped. Even if there's still a mystery, I have a way to work around now, so thanks!